# How do I check if my EditText fields are empty?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 5 `EditTexts` in android. I would like to know if I could check if all 5 `EditTexts` are null. Is there any way to do this??

Answer (score 405, accepted):

I did something like this once;

```
EditText usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
sUsername = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
if (sUsername.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response! So, meaning, I ave 5 editTexts, I have to do that for 5 times??

Comment: not necessarily, that could be a function

Comment: yes sorry, forgot that you had five. You could make a function that did the same thing and call it five times - or you could loop over the five EditText's.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but you do not write functions in java they are called methods...

Comment: if EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER); number this is not working

Comment: @cvaldemar It doesn't work if the user put space on the edittext..

Comment: y'all making it harder than it needs to be: TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText());

Comment: I usually use if (usernameEditText.getText().toString().toString().isEmpty())

Comment: It does not work when user put a space

Comment: @MiralSarwar Try checking the `EditText` value a bit like this: `editText.getText().toString().trim()` (note that I added `.trim()` which should remove additional spaces).

Comment: the simplest yet the most reliable way!

Comment: and I think starting with API 26, class casting is redundant as of date.

Comment: @martyglaubitz - your solution worked perfectly for me thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61766882/edittext-multiple-edit-fill-check 

can You help me out with my problem ??

Comment: Kotlin: if(TextUtils.isEmpty(usernameEditText.text.toString().trim())) { // do something }

Answer (score 201):

```
private boolean isEmpty(EditText etText) {
    if (etText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) 
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

**OR As Per [audrius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181714/audrius)**

```
  private boolean isEmpty(EditText etText) {
        return etText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0;
    }
```

If function return **`false`** means edittext is `not empty` and return **`true`** means edittext is `empty`...

Comment: +1 Checking length is better than checking for empty string IMHO. It would help to trim string before checking length so that whitespace characters wouldn't be counted. Btw, any particular reason of not using `return etText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0` instead of true/false branches?

Comment: well I guess code readability and maintainability...

Comment: if EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER); number then use this.

Comment: Yes its working because its depend on length...

Comment: `private Boolean isEmpty(EditText etText){return etText.Text.ToString().Trim().Length == 0;}` VS 2019

Answer (score 171):

For validating EditText use [EditText#setError](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)  method for show error and for checking empty or null value use inbuilt android class  [TextUtils.isEmpty(strVar)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) which return  true if strVar is null or zero length

```
EditText etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
String strUserName = etUserName.getText().toString();

 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strUserName)) {
    etUserName.setError("Your message");
    return;
 }
```

[image: Image taken from Google search]

Comment: you should add another `)` in the if statement.

Comment: @Androidenthusiasts thanks for pointing it my typo mistake i have update my answer :)

Comment: Couldnt understand the second field ""usernameEditText""

"String strUserName = usernameEditText.getText().toString(); " where does it declared?

Comment: @Sam its my typo i have update my answer `usernameEditText` is `EditText` object and now its renamed to  `etUserName`

Comment: `.toString();` is not required

Comment: what purpose of `return;` is?

Comment: @nandur93 error shown to user and stop going further like save button functionality

Comment: @MilapTank thanks, i just don't get it why Android Studio keeps suggesting to remove that `return;` code.

Comment: Ohk it my requirement so I have added if you don't need then you can remove

Answer (score 39):

try this :

```
EditText txtUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
String strUserName = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
if (strUserName.trim().equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "plz enter your name ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

or use the [TextUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html) class like this :

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strUserName)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "plz enter your name ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Comment: ...this is the best way to do this.  Other examples allow input that is not being accounted for.

Answer (score 31):

Way late to the party here, but I just have to add Android's own [TextUtils.isEmpty(CharSequence str)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

> Returns true if the string is null or 0-length

So if you put your five EditTexts in a list, the full code would be:

```
for(EditText edit : editTextList){
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(edit.getText()){
        // EditText was empty
        // Do something fancy
    }
}
```

Comment: isEmpty() doesnt check for blank space , try entering one space

Comment: @Hunt That's true, but then it would not be empty or null anymore. Maybe TextUtils.isEmpty(sUserName.trim()) would be appropriate, to remove all blanks, just in case the user has entered one or several blank spaces?

Comment: `isEmpty()` takes a `CharSequence`, which `Editable` extends, so there's no need to call `.toString()` on it.

Comment: @karl Good point! Updated my answer.

Answer (score 22):

Other answers are correct but do it in a short way like

```
if(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
     // editText is empty
} else {
     // editText is not empty
}
```

Answer (score 14):

**Try this**

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText());
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `length()` from `EditText`.

```
public boolean isEditTextEmpty(EditText mInput){
   return mInput.length() == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I usually do what [SBJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6290970/2046119) proposes, but the other way around. I simply find it easier to understand my code by checking for positive results instead of double negatives. 
You might be asking for how to check for empty EdiTexts, but what you really want to know is if it has any content and not that it is not empty.

Like so:

```
private boolean hasContent(EditText et) {
    // Always assume false until proven otherwise
    boolean bHasContent = false; 

    if (et.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
        // Got content
        bHasContent = true;
    }
    return bHasContent;
}
```

As [SBJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6290970/2046119) I prefer to return "has no content" (or `false`) as default to avoid exceptions because I borked my content-check. That way you will be absolutely certain that a `true` has been "approved" by your checks.

I also think the `if` calling it looks a bit cleaner as well:

```
if (hasContent(myEditText)) {
// Act upon content
} else {
// Got no content!
}
```

It is very much dependent on preference, but i find this easier to read. :)

Answer (score 7):

Why not just disable the button if EditText is empty?  IMHO This looks more professional:

```
        final EditText txtFrecuencia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFrecuencia);  
        final ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleStartStop);
        txtFrecuencia.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            toggle.setEnabled(txtFrecuencia.length() > 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

        }
       });
```

Comment: Disabling user interfaces is not recommended by Joel Spolsky in [his article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/07/01/dont-hide-or-disable-menu-items/).

Answer (score 4):

I use this method, that uses `trim()` to avoid blank spaces :

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
if ("".equals(myEditText.getText().toString().trim()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a value!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
}
```

an example if you have several EditText´s

```
if (("".equals(edtUser.getText().toString().trim()) || "".equals(edtPassword.getText().toString().trim()))){
        Toast.makeText(this, "a value is missing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(textA.getText())){
            showToast(it's Null");
        }
```

you can use TextUtils.isEmpty like my Example ! 
Good luck

Answer (score 4):

with this short code you can delete empty space at start and end of the string. If the string is "" return the message "error" else you ave a string

```
EditText user = findViewById(R.id.user); 
userString = user.getText().toString().trim(); 
if (userString.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return; 
}else{
     Toast.makeText(this, "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Please add a short explanation of your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61766882/edittext-multiple-edit-fill-check 

can You help me out with my problem ??

Answer (score 3):

```
private boolean hasContent(EditText et) {
       return (et.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used `TextUtils` for this:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(UsernameInfo.getText())) {
    validationError = true;
    validationErrorMessage.append(getResources().getString(R.string.error_blank_username));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also check all the EditText Strings in one If condition: like this

```
if (mString.matches("") || fString.matches("") || gender==null || docString.matches("") || dString.matches("")) {
                Toast.makeText(WriteActivity.this,"Data Incomplete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do something similar. But getting the text value from edit text and comparing it like `(str=="")` wasn't working for me. So better option was:

```
EditText eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etext);

if (etext.getText().length() == 0)
{//do what you want }
```

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out with using If ELSE If conditions. You can validate your editText fields easily.

```
 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
                userNameView.setError("User Name Is Essential");
                return;
         } else  if(TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)) {
                phoneView.setError("Please Enter Your Phone Number");
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could call this function for each of the edit texts:

```
public boolean isEmpty(EditText editText) {
    boolean isEmptyResult = false;
    if (editText.getText().length() == 0) {
        isEmptyResult = true;
    }
    return isEmptyResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText txtUserID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserID);

String UserID = txtUserID.getText().toString();

if (UserID.equals("")) 

{
    Log.d("value","null");
}
```

You will see the message in LogCat....

Answer (score 1):

**"check out this  i m sure you will like it."**

```
log_in.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        username=user_name.getText().toString();
        password=pass_word.getText().toString();
        if(username.equals(""))
        {
            user_name.setError("Enter username");
        }
        else if(password.equals(""))
        {
            pass_word.setError("Enter your password");
        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Scan_QRActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use `TextUtils.isEmpty("Text here");` for single line code

Answer (score 1):

This function work for me

```
private void checkForm() {
    EditText[] allFields = {
        field1_txt,
        field2_txt,
        field3_txt,
        field4_txt
    };
    
    List < EditText > ErrorFields = new ArrayList < EditText > (); 

    for (EditText edit: allFields) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edit.getText())) {

            // EditText was empty
            ErrorFields.add(edit); //add empty Edittext only in this ArayList
            
            for (int i = 0; i < ErrorFields.size(); i++) {
                EditText currentField = ErrorFields.get(i);
                currentField.setError("this field required");
                currentField.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me all in one statement:

```
if(searchText.getText().toString().equals("")) 
    Log.d("MY_LOG", "Empty");
```

First I retrieve a text from the `EditText` and then convert it to a string and finally comparing it with `""` using `.equals` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Edt);

String data=edt.getText().toString();

if(data=="" || data==null){

 Log.e("edit text is null?","yes");

}

else {

 Log.e("edit text is null?","no");

}
```

do like this for all five edit text

Answer (score 0):

To editText is empty try another this simple way :

```
String star = editText.getText().toString();

if (star.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Set start no", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: why ignore case?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setOnFocusChangeListener` , it will check when focus change

```
        txt_membername.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
            if (arg1) {
                //do something
            } else {
                if (txt_membername.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    txt_membername
                            .setError("Member name is not empty, Plz!");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( (usernameEditText.getText()+"").equals("") ) { 
    // Really just another way
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [ButterKnife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) list binding and then applying actions on the list. For example, with the case of EditTexts, I have the following custom actions defined in a utility class (in this case `ButterKnifeActions`)

```
public static <V extends View> boolean checkAll(List<V> views, ButterKnifeActions.Check<V> checker) {
    boolean hasProperty = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++) {
        hasProperty = checker.checkViewProperty(views.get(i), i) && hasProperty;
    }
    return hasProperty;
}

public static <V extends View> boolean checkAny(List<V> views, ButterKnifeActions.Check<V> checker) {
    boolean hasProperty = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++) {
        hasProperty = checker.checkViewProperty(views.get(i), i) || hasProperty;
    }
    return hasProperty;
}

public interface Check<V extends View> {
    boolean checkViewProperty(V view, int index);
}

public static final ButterKnifeActions.Check<EditText> EMPTY = new Check<EditText>() {
    @Override
    public boolean checkViewProperty(EditText view, int index) {
        return TextUtils.isEmpty(view.getText());
    }
};
```

And in the view code, I bind the EditTexts to a list and apply the actions when I need to check the views.

```
@Bind({R.id.edit1, R.id.edit2, R.id.edit3, R.id.edit4, R.id.edit5}) List<EditView> edits;
...
if (ButterKnifeActions.checkAny(edits, ButterKnifeActions.EMPTY)) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And of course this pattern is extendable to checking any property on any number of views. The only downside, if you can call it that, is the redundancy of views. Meaning, to use those EditTexts, you would have to bind them to single variables as well so that you can reference them by name or you would have to reference them by position in the list (`edits.get(0)`, etc.). Personally, I just bind each of them twice, once to a single variable and once to a the list and use whichever is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:
its in Kotlin

```
//button from xml
button.setOnClickListener{                                         
    val new=addText.text.toString()//addText is an EditText
    if(new=isNotEmpty())
    {
         //do something
    }
    else{
        new.setError("Enter some msg")
        //or
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Enter some message ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Thank you