# Android: Check if EditText is Empty when inputType is set on Number/Phone

Tags: android, android-edittext, gettext

I have an EditText in android for users to input their AGE. It is set an inputType=phone. 
I would like to know if **there is a way to check if this EditText is null**.

I've already looked at this question: [Check if EditText is empty.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290531/check-if-edittext-is-empty) but it does not address the case where inputType=phone.

These, I've checked already and do not work:

```
(EditText) findViewByID(R.id.age)).getText().toString() == null
(EditText) findViewByID(R.id.age)).getText().toString() == ""
(EditText) findViewByID(R.id.age)).getText().toString().matches("")
(EditText) findViewByID(R.id.age)).getText().toString().equals("")
(EditText) findViewByID(R.id.age)).getText().toString().equals(null)
(EditText) findViewByID(R.id.age)).getText().toString().trim().length() == 0
(EditText) findViewByID(R.id.age)).getText().toString().trim().equals("")
and isEmpty do not check for blank space.
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Exactly what you need???

Comment: is there a way to check if the EditText set with inputType=phone is null

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with `inputType`.

Comment: Duplicate(?) of [Check if EditText is empty.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6290531/456814).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can check using the TextUtils class like

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(ed_text);
```

or you can check like this:

```
EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);

String ed_text = ed.getText().toString().trim();

if(ed_text.isEmpty() || ed_text.length() == 0 || ed_text.equals("") || ed_text == null)
{
    //EditText is empty
}
else
{
    //EditText is not empty
}
```

Comment: No need for `ed_text == null`. It can't be null here.

Comment: and instead `TextUtils.isEmpty(ed_text)` would be more readable.

Comment: `ed_text.getText().toString().isEmpty()`

Answer (score 6):

**First Method**

Use **TextUtil library**

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString()) 
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "plz enter your name ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

**Second Method**

```
private boolean isEmpty(EditText etText) 
{
        return etText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0;
}
```

Comment: error: incompatible types: EditText cannot be converted to CharSequence so cannot be checked by isEmpty

Comment: Use first method but don't forget to call getText().toString()

Answer (score 2):

### Add Kotlin getter functions

```
val EditText.empty get() = text.isEmpty() // it == ""
// and/or
val EditText.blank get() = text.isBlank() // it.trim() == ""
```

With these, you can just use `if (edittext.empty) ...` or `if (edittext.blank) ...`

If you don't want to extend this functionality, the original Kotlin is:

```
edittext.text.isBlank()
// or
edittext.text.isEmpty()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText textAge;
textAge = (EditText)findViewByID(R.id.age);
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(textAge))
{
Toast.makeText(this, "Age Edit text is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//or type here the code you want
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answering questions here is good but a good answer is more than just code. When answering an old question it is helpful to add significant new information and new insights to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method for same works:

```
public boolean checkIsNull(EditText... editTexts){
for (EditText editText: editTexts){
  if(editText.getText().length() == 0){
    return true;
  }
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the following

```
String s = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.age)).getText().toString();
TextUtils.isEmpty(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that these tests fail if a user enters a space so I test for a missing hint for empty value

```
EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);

EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

// these hint strings reflect the hints attached to the resources

if (username.getHint().equals("Enter your username") || password.getHint().equals("Enter Your Password")){
      // enter your code here 

} else {
      // alls well
}
```

Comment: there is a typepo! 

EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword) ..

should be on a new line nd is not part of the comment

Answer (score 0):

editText.length() usually works for me
try this one

```
if((EditText) findViewByID(R.id.age)).length()==0){
   //do whatever when the field is null`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java: Check if EditText is Empty

#### 1) find the EditText

```
 ourEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
```

#### 2) Get String value of EditText

```
 String ourEditTextString = ourEditText.getText().toString();
```

#### 3) Remove all spaces

- Incase user inputs only blank spaces.

```
String ourEditTextNoSpaces = ourEditTextString.replaceAll(" ","");
```

#### 3) Check if empty

```
boolean isOurEditTextEmpty = ourEditTextNoSpaces.isEmpty();
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this. This is the only solution I got**

```java
String phone;   

 try{
phone=(EditText) findViewByID(R.id.age)).getText().toString();

}
catch(NumberFormatException e){

 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "plz enterphone Number ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;

}
```