# Want to display an error message if the value is NULL or VOID if EditText is empty but apps keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, crash

```
public void add(View v)
{

    EditText first=findViewById(R.id.first),second=findViewById(R.id.second);
    double f=Double.parseDouble(first.getText().toString());
    double s=Double.parseDouble(second.getText().toString());
    TextView result=findViewById(R.id.result);
    double r;
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(first.getText().toString()))
    {
        first.setError("This field can't be empty");
    }
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(second.getText().toString()))
    {
        second.setError("This field can't be empty");
    }
    else {
        r = f + s;
        result.setText("" + r);
    }

}
```

I want to add two numbers from taking input from user and display an error msg if editText is empty.
But on executing this piece of code my app keeps crashing.

Comment: share error logcat.

Comment: check this link to check is empty or not https://stackoverflow.com/a/20349649/7642429

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You   need convert your `Editext` value in to `Double` if `Editext` value  is not empty

Try this

```
public void add(View v)
{

    EditText first=findViewById(R.id.first);
    EditText second=findViewById(R.id.second);      

    TextView result=findViewById(R.id.result);

    double r;

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(first.getText().toString()))
    {
        first.setError("This field can't be empty");
    }
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(second.getText().toString()))
    {
        second.setError("This field can't be empty");
    }
    else {
        double s=Double.parseDouble(second.getText().toString());
        double f=Double.parseDouble(first.getText().toString());
        r = f + s;
        result.setText("" + r);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah it worked perfectly for me. Can you point out what's my mistake ?

Comment: @Vivank the problem is if your `Editext value` is empty than your can't convert in tio a double  and you will get number format exception

Comment: @Vivank please accept and upvote this ans if it help you

Comment: Yeah after 2 minutes @Prem . I was trying to do that from the beginning itself but it needs 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

1. Add "null" check ,before the empty check

eg :

```
if((first.gettext().toString) == null ||
    TextUtils.isEmpty(first.getText().toString()))
        {
            first.setError("This field can't be empty");
        }
        else if((second.gettext().toString) == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(second.getText().toString()))
        {
            second.setError("This field can't be empty");
        }
        else {
            r = f + s;
            result.setText("" + r);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare first,second globally

```
public void add(View v) {
    first = findViewById(R.id.first);
    second = findViewById(R.id.second);
    TextView result = findViewById(R.id.result);
    double r;
    if (Validates()) {
        double s = Double.parseDouble(second.getText().toString());
        double f = Double.parseDouble(first.getText().toString());
        r = f + s;
        result.setText("" + r);
    }
}


public boolean Validates() {
    if (first.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        first.setError("This field can't be empty");
        return false;
    } else if (second.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        second.setError("This field can't be empty");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```