# Checking for empty edittext android

Tags: android

I have an edittext with input type set to number. I want to check if edittext is empty.

```
 <EditText
   android:id="@+id/noOfTranset"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
   android:hint="Enter number:"
   android:inputType="number"
   android:textColor="@android:color/black"
   android:maxLength="2"/>
```

Below is the code which I have tried but doesn't checks for empty edittext. What am I missing here? Thanks.

```
String numTrans = et1.getText().toString();
int transaction = Integer.parseInt(numTrans);



if(numTrans.trim().length() == 0 || numTrans.equals("") || numTrans == null){

// none of the above conditions check for empty edittext

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your trying to convert the `empty string` to an `Integer`. `Integer.parseInt` will throw `NumberFormatException` when the input text is `null` or `empty`.

Change your code to parse `string to integer` only when the input text is not empty

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(numTrans)){
      int transaction = Integer.parseInt(numTrans);
      // do your other stuff here
 }
```

Comment: Nope, still not working. Here is the logcat05-07 18:43:12.174: E/AndroidRuntime(910): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 18:43:12.174: E/AndroidRuntime(910): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
05-07 18:43:12.174: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
05-07 18:43:12.174: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
05-07 18:43:12.174: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)

Comment: You are correct. After changing the code if(TextUtils.isEmpty(numTrans)){
     
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error! Enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     return;
     
    }
    
    
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(numTrans))
    
    transaction = Integer.parseInt(numTrans);
    }

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
EditText usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
sUsername = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
if (sUsername.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Taken from:  [Check if EditText is empty.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290531/check-if-edittext-is-empty)

Comment: Since it is a number edittext, it's expecting a numeric input. Is it possible to check for null value in int?

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple you should check by using `trim function` like:

```
String numTrans = et1.getText().toString();

if(!numTrans.trim().length() > 0)
{
    int transaction = Integer.parseInt(numTrans);   
    //code here for empty edittext....

}
```