# (Android) Check if EditText is empty?

Tags: java, android

How do you check if an `EditText` is empty?  I want to make it so that if the `EditText` is blank, a `TextView` value will be " " (space).  If it's not, resume as normal.  How do I go about doing this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

to check Edittext as empty ,where `myeditText` is your edittext

```
if(myeditText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
```

Or use below function

```
   private boolean isEmpty(EditText myeditText) {
            return myeditText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0;
        }
```

If function return `false` means edittext is not empty and return `true` means edittext is empty

For more info see this best link [Check if EditText is empty.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290531/check-if-edittext-is-empty)

Answer (score 1):

`EditText` has a method `getText()` which returns an instance of `Editable` and the `Editable` class has a method: `length()`. If the lenght is not 0, your `EditText` is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

```java
String text=yourEditText.getText().toString().trim();
if(text.equal("") || text==null) {
    //Do Somthing...
} 
else {
    //Do something else
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you go through `EditText` API reference, `getText()` will return the text as `Editable`. You can use it like

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(myeditText.getText().toString().trim()) {
// Non-empty 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method from android framework

```
public static boolean isEmpty (CharSequence str)
Added in API level 1

Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.
Parameters
str     the string to be examined
Returns

    true if str is null or zero length
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: if(myeditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){ } user this pattern