# How to check EditText isEmpty in Android

Tags: android

I want to create a **login page**, I used `EditText` to insert user info. I want to check `EditText` to see if it is Empty **Invisible** login Button, when inserted any character with user **visible** Login Button.
I tried the code shown below, but it did not not work for me :

```
//Show Login Button
String login_phoneString = login_PhoneText.getText().toString().trim();
if (login_phoneString.isEmpty()) {
    login_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
} else {
    login_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

When `EditText` is empty, the button is invisible, and when set character in `EditText` again the login button is not shown.

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Android) Check if EditText is empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391809/android-check-if-edittext-is-empty)

Comment: try to use `TextWatcher()` on your `EditText` as per the answer by Phan Van Linh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show/hide the `Login button` base on the text of `EditText` so you need to listen for changing in `EditText` by use `TextWatcher`.
Use this code inside `onCreate()` method

```
login_PhoneText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String login_phoneString = login_PhoneText.getText().toString().trim();
            if (login_phoneString.isEmpty()) {
                login_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                login_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `trim()`

```
if(et.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) //empty
```

Using `TextUtils`

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(et.getText().toString().trim()) //Empty
```

Using `isEmpty()`

```
if(et.getText().toString().isEmpty()) //Empty
```

### EDIT

You can do this :

```
//Show Login Button
String login_phoneString = login_PhoneText.getText().toString().trim();
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(login_phoneString) {
   login_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
} else {
   login_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check like this way

```
    EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    String abc = edt.getText().toString();
    if (abc.matches("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "enter something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        login_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
      login_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String login_phoneString = login_PhoneText.getText().toString().trim();
if (login_phoneString.equals("")) {
    login_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    login_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Use View.GONE instead of INVISIBLE. when INVISIBLE it is still clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Use TextUtils.isEmpty():

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(yourEditText.getText().toString())) {
    //Empty
} else {
    //Not empty
}
```

Comment: Then your problem is somewhere else

Comment: `if (TextUtils.isEmpty(login_PhoneText.getText().toString())) {
            login_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            login_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }`     not work