# Android Studio if editText is empty

Tags: android-studio, android-edittext

I'm new to Android Studio, I want to display a toast when a button is pressed if one or both of two editText fields is empty? I've tried for 5 hours; about to die.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if EditText is empty.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290531/check-if-edittext-is-empty)

Comment: please post your java file .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, create a new method in your class if you haven't already:

```
    public void checkIfEmpty(View v){
    if(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty() & editText2.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
       Toast.makeText(this, "EditText is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

And in your xml, be sure to set the onClick to that method. If you're new to java and you didn't understand tell me.

Comment: Hey it worked but I'm trying to open a new activity if it is false. The code I have here opens the new activity regardless.

Comment: public void log_in_sends_2(View view) {
        if (EditUsername.getText().toString().isEmpty() & EditPassword.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "EditText is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            {
                String LogIn_Button;
                LogIn_Button = ((Button) view).getText().toString();
                 if (LogIn_Button.equals("Log In")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LogIn.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set an `onClickListener` to your button. Then, inside it, add this code:

```
if(mTextView.getText().toString().equals("")){
  makeToast(mContext, "TextView is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

A few notes about this:

- mTextView and mContext are initialized in your Java class outside the listener, so in order to use inside it they have to be declared `final`
- When you call `makeToast` **always** remember to call `show()` at the end or it will **never be displayed**

Comment: What do you mean by declared final?

Comment: Also I tries to use this code to set an onClickListener for the button by I'm getting errors, Button LogInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.I'd.button_logIn_Main); LogInButton.setonClickListener(new Button.on.ClickListener() { public void  mybuttonid = (View view) { \\other code }

Comment: By final I mean like this: final Context mContext = getActivity (); final TextView mTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById (R.id.myView); If you have other errors, please post them.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy Answer by cvaldemar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290531/check-if-edittext-is-empty)

```
EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userEmail);
name = text1.getText().toString();
email = text2.getText().toString();
if (name.matches("") || email.matches(""))
 {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Comment: You need to create the id by which you are fetching the EditTextFields in xml file

Comment: After that you will be able to fetch the fields, the above id's are just for demos. This is how you can fetch the EditText and apply the condition and display the Toast.

Answer (score 0):

```
Take values from editText on button click and compare them with string .

 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                strEdt1 = editText1.getText().toString();
                strEdt2 =  editText2.getText().toString();;
                if (editText1.isEmpty() && editText2.isEmpty()) {
                    // Toast for editText1
                    editText1.requestFocus();
                }
                else if (editText2.isEmpty()) {
                    //  Toast for editText2
                    editText2.requestFocus();
                }
        else if (editText1.isEmpty()) {
                    //  Toast for editText2
                    editText1.requestFocus();
                }

            }
        });
```