# Login button is not working Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a simple login form with SharedPreferences.I have put some basic user validation but it is not working. When I enter the username and password and click login button, nothing gets displayed. It should if it is wrong username and password. Below is the code for same.

```
  val userName = findViewById(R.id.user) as EditText
        val password = findViewById(R.id.pass) as EditText
        val b1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1) as Button

        b1.setOnClickListener {

            if (userName.equals("")  || password.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            else if (userName.equals("John") and password.equals("123"))
            {
                val editor = getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                editor.putString("name", userName.getText().toString())
                editor.apply()
                val intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("name", userName.toString())
                startActivity(intent)

            }

      else
           {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password Do not Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           }


        }
```

Comment: Try like this `userName.text.equals("")` and `userName.text.equals("John")`

Comment: Could you debug and check where the flow is going. Agree with Anas

Comment: userName.text.equals("") i tied this sir not working

Comment: use userName.text.equals at all places in your above code instead of simple userName.equals

Comment: userName.text.equals i used like all places of above code not working

Comment: try userName.text.toString().equals("")

Comment: it working L2_Paver thanks for your kind help

Comment: Please do not edit your question with fixes that answer your question, as it confuses everyone. I've undone your edit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like the following.

```
b1.setOnClickListener {
   val name:String = userName.text.toString()
   val pass:String = password.text.toString()

   if (name.trim().length == 0  || pass.trim().length == 0){
         Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
   }
   else if (name.equals("John") and pass.equals("123")){
         val editor = getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
         editor.putString("name", name)
         editor.apply()
         val intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
         intent.putExtra("name", name)
         startActivity(intent)

   }
   else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password Do not Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The matches will be the best option for this kind of validation things

```
sUsername = userName.text;
if (sUsername.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

reference question : [Check if EditText is empty.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290531/check-if-edittext-is-empty)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if (userName.text.isNullOrEmpty()){
                userName.error = "Enter username"
            }
            else if (password.text.isNullOrEmpty()){
                password.error = "Enter password"
            }
            else if (userName.text.toString() == "john" && password.text.toString() == "123"){

                val editor = getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                editor.putString("name", userName.getText().toString())
                editor.apply()
                val intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("name", userName.toString())
                startActivity(intent)

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b1.setOnClickListener {

            if (userName.text.toString().equals("") || password.text.toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else if (userName.text.toString().equals("John") and password.text.toString().equals("123")) {
                 val editor = getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                            editor.putString("name", userName.getText().toString())
                            editor.apply()
                           val intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
                           intent.putExtra("name", userName.toString())
                           startActivity(intent)
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password Do not Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b1.setOnClickListener {view ->

       if (userName.text.isNullOrEmpty()  || password.text.isNullOrEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else if (userName.text.equals("John") and password.text.equals("123")){
            val editor = getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            editor.putString("name", userName.getText().toString())
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("name", userName.toString())
            startActivity(intent)

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have added

> apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'.

in your app level gradle. Using this there is not need to use findViewById. You can directly access views from layout.

So if you have `Edittext` with id `edit`.

then in your code you can directly use that as below

```
if(edit.text.isEmpty())
{
// Your code
}
```

or

```
if(edit.text.equals("")
{
// Your code
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
b1.setOnClickListener {
    if (userName.text.isEmpty() || password.text.isEmpty())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    else if (userName.text == "John" && password.text == "123")
    {
        val editor = getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
        editor.putString("name", userName.getText().toString())
        editor.apply()
        val intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("name", userName.toString())
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting your `Edittext` into string you have just assigned the id to your `Edittext` and it would still be treated as a `Edittext` field. You have to pass the **string value**, not a `Editext`. To convert it into string, your `if` condition must be like this:

```
 if (userName.text.toString().trim().equals("")  || password.text.toString().trim().equals("")) {
 Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
```

Or you can do it while assigning the id, like so:

```
val uName = userName.text.toString().trim()
val userPass = password.text.toString().trim()
```

then your `if` condition will be like this:

```
if (uName.equals("")  || userPass.equals("")) {
 Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
```