# I want to know "how to check that edittext is empty on button click" in kotlin, android studio because my code is not working

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is my code, and there is no problem in XML all the ids of the views are correct

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        val stringInTextField:EditText = findViewById(R.id.bill)
        button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener{
        val userInput = stringInTextField.text.toString()
        if (userInput.isEmpty) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter the Bill", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what error you are getting?

Comment: You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6290970/16210149). Hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your code, since `String` class has no property `isEmpty` but a method `isEmpty()`. So fix that error in order to make it work:

```
if (userInput.isEmpty()) { // Here is the fix
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter the Bill", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code `if (!userInput.equals(""))`

Comment: Thank you, for giving a short method :)